# Insert Special character in sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I try this code.

```
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Bookmark(Names,Details) Values('%@','%@')", delegate.str, delegate.str1];

    NSLog(@"%@",query);

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if (sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String],&database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
                NSLog( @"Error while inserting data: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            else
                NSLog(@"New data inserted");

            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        }else
        {
            NSLog( @"Error while inserting '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
```

This is i want to store sqlite INSERT INTO Bookmark(Details) Values('Let's take an example, 23456789 divided by 7, 11, 13.

Make triplets as shown starting from unit's place.

23...456...789

Now add alternate triplets :

23 + 789 = 812 and 456.

Difference of these two sums :
812 - 456 = 356

Now divide this difference by 7, we get reminder 6

And divide this difference by 11, we get reminder 4

And divide this difference by 13, we get reminder 5')

And this the error after write your line...

2013-07-25 16:38:14.653 Maths Tricks Tips Patterns[4346:c07] Error while inserting 'near "s": syntax error'

How may i insert special charcter please help me out this thanks in advance.

Comment: You should NEVER form SQL queries manually using stringWithFormat etc. Use the standard sqlite APIs for variable binding / prepared statements.

Comment: Error while inserting 'near "s": syntax error'    this is the log

Comment: `Values('Let's take an...` -- Do you see anything wrong there???  (You wouldn't have this problem if you used a prepared statement and variable binding.)

Answer (score 3):

You should NEVER form SQL queries manually using stringWithFormat etc.

Instead you should use prepared statements with variable binding. This will ensure the correct encoding and avoid SQL injections etc. You should begin by looking at [this sqlite introduction](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

The basic pattern is to use `sqlite3_prepare` followed by something like `sqlite3_bind_text` to set the value for one of the `?` placeholders in your query.

Comment: SQL injections?  Pardon me, but who is going to inject what when you run an iOS application on your own device?

Comment: I simply mean you avoid people accidentally using characters like `'` and breaking the app. Also, I would never rule out security concerns without knowing more about the application.