# How to properly escape single quotes in SQLite insert statement - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, insert

I have an insert statement for my sqlite table that contains apostrophes in the values.

```
NSString *sqlInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into myTable (_id, name, area, title, description, url) VALUES (%i, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", tempObject.ID, tempObject.name, tempObject.area, tempObject.title, tempObject.description, tempObject.url];
```

The results of that string is this

```
insert into myTable (_id, name, area, title, description, url) VALUES (0, 'John Smith', 'USA', 'Programmer', 'John Smith is a programmer. He programs a lot. John Smith's duty is to program. He loves it. His dog's name is Billy.', 'www.google.com')
```

When I try to insert that into the table, I get a syntax error near "s". I want to properly escape the apostrophes. How would I go about doing that? Thanks, any insight is appreciated!

**Edit:** We have solved our issue. We had entered some single quotes (') into our strings where we really wanted curly single quotes. The curly single quotes do not mess with the SQLite insert statements. **For those who have this problem, you could possibly use single curly quotes instead of regular single quotes.** This may not be possible in your circumstances, but for some it could be a simple solution.

Comment: Don't use `stringWithFormat` to build your query. Do it properly with `sqlite3_bind_xxx` statements.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855029/insert-special-character-in-sqlite/17855164#17855164

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your data contains single quote in it. You have two option to overcome this.

1. Escape `'` with `\'`
2. Use [sqlite3_bind_xxx()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) method for binding the values ( I prefer this method). You can do it like:

```
NSString *sqlInsert =  @"insert into myTable (_id, name, area, title, description, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if (sqlite3_open([yourDBPath UTF8String], &yourDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(yourDB, sql, 1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, tempObject.ID);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [tempObject.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [tempObject.area UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [tempObject.title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [tempObject.description UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [tempObject.url UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      // Execute
   }
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the column indexes of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` are 1-based but the column indexes of `sqlite3_column_xxx` are 0-based? Drives me nuts (sorry, rant over). :)

Comment: @rmaddy I think it is because `sqlite3_bind_xxx` should work for named parameters too, and `sqlite3_bind_parameter_index` returns 0 as error code (when there's no matching parameter present).

Comment: In SQL, single quotes are not escaped with a backslash.

Comment: @rmaddy: I think it's too late, but I found the answer for your question. *The index for named parameters can be looked up using the sqlite3_bind_parameter_index() API if desired.* [Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). But that function will return 0 if there is no match found, that's why the index is starting from 1 for sqlite3_bind_xxx. (*A zero is returned if no matching parameter is found.* [Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_index.html) )

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks but Alex Skalozub posted that same info in a comment just after mine.

Comment: @rmaddy: ha ha, saw that. :) Thanks for your time :)